# ReactNative navigation-looking for best way to load many screens dynamically?

Tags: performance, react-native, navigation

As we are aware that we can use the react-navigation for handling the navigation with multiple screens in react native app, my question is- Consider we have a to load a sequence of more than 300 screens dynamically, then what is the best way to handle this scenario? 
The screens can be templates which will render differently based on the data loaded each time. Say I may have 30 types of different templates and each one need the API data for rendering the layout. The total 300 screens are a kind of repeating templates from the 30 different types. This is an app something based on e-learning platform.
Appreciate your suggestions in advance

Comment: could you please represent  more obvious question ?